# Use user input within as input in a function Python

Tags: python

I'm currently having some trouble with this in Python 3. I've tried to figure out how to use the user input stored in `income` and `pension_contribution` in the `pension()` but nothing is happening. Where should those user inputs go in order to be considered input so the function can work?

```
income = input(int("What is your annual income?"))
pension_contribution = input(int("What is your monthly pension contribution?"))

def pension(pension_contribution, income):
    if pension_contribution > ((income//12) * .075):
        print ("Your pension contribution is too high. Monthly pension contributions may not exceed 7.5% of your gross monthly income")
    else:
        print("Your annual pension contribution is R", pension_contribution * 12)
```

Comment: Your input statement is missing a paren...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You could do this 3 different ways:

**1. Simply call the function**

```
def pension (pension_contribution, income):

    if pension_contribution > ((income//12) * .075):
        print ("Your pension contribution is too high. Monthly pension contributions may not exceed 7.5% of your gross monthly income")

    else:
        print("Your annual pension contribution is R", pension_contribution * 12)

income = int(input("What is your annual income?"))
pension_contribution = int(input("What is your monthly pension contribution?")) 

pension(pension_contribution, income) #call function
```

**2. Put variables inside the function**

```
def pension ():
    income = int(input("What is your annual income?"))
    pension_contribution = int(input("What is your monthly pension contribution?"))
    if pension_contribution > ((income//12) * .075):
        print ("Your pension contribution is too high. Monthly pension contributions may not exceed 7.5% of your gross monthly income")

    else:
        print("Your annual pension contribution is R", pension_contribution * 12)


pension() #still have to call function
```

**2. Global variables** (not recommended)

```
income = int(input("What is your annual income?"))
pension_contribution = int(input("What is your monthly pension contribution?"))

def pension ():
    global income, pension_contribution
    if pension_contribution > ((income//12) * .075):
        print ("Your pension contribution is too high. Monthly pension contributions may not exceed 7.5% of your gross monthly income")

    else:
        print("Your annual pension contribution is R", pension_contribution * 12)

pension() #still have to call function
```

*Notice how you have to actually "call" the function every time. Otherwise the program would run successfully but never bother entering the function.*

Comment: Thanks everyone. Your comments were super helpful. Just a follow up question though. If I want to re-use the income variable for instance (without prompting the use again)  how should I do this? The second and first options appears to be part of the function and I won't be able to use it in another function?

Comment: @Rooirokbokkie The first option has variables outside the function (notice the difference in indentation). Simply calling the function is what you want, because it only asks the user for inputs once. Only use option 2 if you want to ask the user for input more than once.

Comment: Actually there is a fourth option. You can read variables from the global scope without using the ```global``` keyword, but you cannot write to them. This is because of the way Python looks up variable names and the immutability of ```int```s. This method is basically option 3, but without the global line.

Comment: And the fifth and best option (if you plan on using ```income``` and ```pension_contribution``` in other functions) is to use a class.

Answer (score 2):

1) Your indentation seems to be off
2) You need to call the function

```
income = input(int("What is your annual income?"))
pension_contribution = input(int("What is your monthly pension contribution?"))

def pension (pension_contribution, income):

    if pension_contribution > ((income//12) * .075):
        print ("Your pension contribution is too high. Monthly pension contributions may not exceed 7.5% of your gross monthly income")

    else:
        print("Your annual pension contribution is R", pension_contribution * 12)

pension(pension_contribution, income)
```